# Depending on event-status show attending-button

Tags: javascript, facebook, events

I've built a check for current rsvp_status for an event and the currently logged in member. Now I'd like to show an I'm attending button depending on someone's status. I can work out the HTML for the different buttons depending on their RSVP-status, but what I'm not sure of is how to write someone's rsvp_status back into the Graph after clicking the "I'm attending" button... Can you guys give me a push in the right direction?

Thanks!

Steven

Comment: Does anyone know if this is possible with the JS-SDK or that I need to use PHP for it.. as far as I can work out my $.post()'s to the proper graph URL get blocked because of crossdomain-policy...

Answer (score 0):

You can post back attending status, this requires two things:

1. you have to have the rsvp_event permission for that user, and

   you have to call 
   `FB.api(eventID+'/attending', 'post', function(resp) { // true if the rsvp was successfull })`

This will check the user in the event.

For more info, see [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/)